Is there any 32bit extensions for Chrome running on a Chromecast dongle
I have a TV displaying machine metrics from a secure website on a Chromecast dongle. I have made a webpage that displays our shops 5S dashboard. I want to be able to switch from the machine metrics webpage to the 5S dashboard webpage at regular intervals. There are several browser extensions available to accomplish this but they are all for 64-bit systems. Chrome is up-to-date but only a 32-bit. I have tried to make an HTML file to switch between the two pages but the secure page is not allowing it. I have made a custom chrome extension that switches tabs but it only works on my 64-bit machine. I have looked at kiosk apps but was a bit confused about whether they would work for my needs. Is there any suggestions out there? Whenever I go to install an extension it says that chrome needs to be updated...

What am I missing?  I don't understand the downvotes.

What you need to do is visit the legacy store, which at this time still works but only if you enter it directly into the address bar or click the link.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/old
This will bring you to extensions for Chrome that should work in older versions.
